# Why am I not getting payments on my bitcoind on an amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoind, network, amazon-web-services

I have an amazon ec2 instance running a web server, MySQL server, and bitcoin daemon on ubuntu 14.04, and I ran ./bitcoind getnewaddress and the output was an address. I sent a few cents worth of bitcoin to that address, and I have been doing ./bitcoind getbalance for a few hours and **still** there is no balance.

Wondering if I needed to send to a particular accoutn instead of the main bitcoin daemon, I also sent a few cents to an address generated by ./bitcoind getnewaddress debug (just a test name) and did ./bitcoind getbalance debug. I have found nothing, I am not sure what the issue is. Port 8333 is open on the amazon vm, so I don't think the issue is there. bitcoind's rpc interface is running on port 8432 as specified by rpcport=8432 in ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf. Any idea why I am not getting payments? I think there have been enough confirmations, I believe the number required is 6 required by default. I will check soon to make sure that there have been that many confirmations.

Comment: Is your client synched? What is core's response on `bitcoin-cli getblockcount`?

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis 281034, I'll check if that's up to date, one second please... (I started this bitcoind very recently, so maybe it hasn't finished syncing...)

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis Grr, thats about 50,000 blocks behind. Does that mean I have to wait a few hours still?

Comment: Yes, 281034 is mid January. This is the reason your transactions haven't appeared yet in your client.

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis Alright, thanks. By the way, I am a free tier user of amazon and so I do not have very much storage on my server, 20 GB right now (I can get up to 30 if needed, I will probably have to). My storage is about 90% full, and I'm pretty sure that's because of the blockchain. Is there any way to only use the recent blocks or something so that I don't use this much storage?

Comment: 20 GB are not enough but 30 won't do either. The current size of the blockchain is 30.4 GB (32.731.154.471 bytes). The pruning feature is not still available but will be included in one of the upcoming versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18843/discussion-between-user16871-and-george-kimionis).

Answer (score 1):

Your client needs to be fully synchronized for your transactions to show up, otherwise it's not aware that these transactions ever took place.